# Как выделить слова предложения жирным и вывести их списком?

Tags: python

На вход поступает строка из слов. Нужно все слова выделить жирным и вывести списком.

```
import re
class color:
   BOLD = '\033[1m'
   END = '\033[0m'

st = color.BOLD + 'Придет осень и спросит' + color.END
wordList = re.sub("[^\w]", " ", st).split()

print(wordList)
```

Почему выводит это и не выделяет, хотя если не создавать списка, то выводится жирным?

```
['1mПридет', 'осень', 'и', 'спросит', '0m']
```

Вместо
['**Придет**', '**осень'**, '**и**', '**спросит**']
Как исправить?

Comment: Так вы сами удалили все небуквы из строки…

Comment: Очевидно сначала разделить на слова, а потом каждое слово сделать жирным

Answer (score 0):

Сначала чистить предложение от непечатных символов, а потом уже оборачивать каждое слово в спецсимволы. Но в виде списка всё-равно жирным печататься не будет, только в виде строки:

```
import re
class color:
   BOLD = '\033[1m'
   END = '\033[0m'

st = 'Придет осень и спросит'
wordList = re.sub("[^\w]", " ", st).split()
make_bold = lambda x: color.BOLD + x + color.END
boldList = list(map(make_bold, wordList))

print(boldList)
print(*boldList)
```

Вывод:

```
['\x1b[1mПридет\x1b[0m',
 '\x1b[1mосень\x1b[0m',
 '\x1b[1mи\x1b[0m',
 '\x1b[1mспросит\x1b[0m']
```

**Придет осень и спросит**